# Three.js - update Mesh Colour of Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a Three.js `Object3D` that I would like to update the colour of.

I originally construct the Mesh using a `MeshStandardMaterial` and add it into the scene. Later, I look up this object by ID and retrieve an `Object3D` from the scene. How can I update the colour of the Mesh at this point - is it possible?

If I have to delete the 3D object and add an entirely new one - is there a way to retrieve the geometry that was originally used to construct it from the `Object3D` itself? I would rather not store a mapping of the original geometry to an object's ID, as this would make the code messy. One option I can think of is to store the geometry on `Object3D.UserData`, but this is again suboptimal as currently the Meshes are constructed elsewhere - and then added to the scene (user data is available only once it has been added to the scene).

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to add `texture` into a `Object3D`.

You can map `children` property to update material of meshes.

```js
    function onLoad(object) {
      // `children` is an array of `Mesh` than contain 1 or more Meshes
      object.children.forEach((mesh) => {
        if (!mesh) return;
        const material = mesh.material;

        material.map = ghostColorTexture;
        material.normalMap = ghostNormalTexture;
      });
    }

    const objLoader = new OBJLoader();

    objLoader.load(
      '/models/ghost/model/ghost.obj',
      onLoad,
      undefined,
      function (error) {
        console.error('error', error);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score -4):

An `Object3D` can be a `Mesh` that's composed of a `Geometry` and a `Material`. If you want to update the color, simply select that material, and assign a new color to it:

`object.material.color.setHex(0xff9900); // Sets to orange`

In the docs, you can see that [`.color` is a property of `MeshStandardMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.color) and [`.material` is a property of `Mesh`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh.material)